# SWFUpload: How to cancel an upload in Classic Form

Tags: php, javascript, swfupload

I am using the classic form demo. The link is: [link text](http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/formsdemo/index.php)

If you try out the demo & try to upload a file, you can see once you click on the "Submit Application" button, the cancel (cross image) button does not show up in the top right hand corner of the blue box (that indicates the progress). How can I manipulate the existing code to be able to see the cancel button & cancel the upload while it is in progress?

Current JS code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var swfu;

  window.onload = function () {
   swfu = new SWFUpload({
    // Backend settings
    upload_url: "upload.php",
    file_post_name: "resume_file",

    // Flash file settings
    file_size_limit : "10 MB",
    file_types : "*.*",   // or you could use something like: "*.doc;*.wpd;*.pdf",
    file_types_description : "All Files",
    file_upload_limit : "0",
    file_queue_limit : "1",

    // Event handler settings
    swfupload_loaded_handler : swfUploadLoaded,

    file_dialog_start_handler: fileDialogStart,
    file_queued_handler : fileQueued,
    file_queue_error_handler : fileQueueError,
    file_dialog_complete_handler : fileDialogComplete,

    //upload_start_handler : uploadStart, // I could do some client/JavaScript validation here, but I don't need to.
    upload_progress_handler : uploadProgress,
    upload_error_handler : uploadError,
    upload_success_handler : uploadSuccess,
    upload_complete_handler : uploadComplete,

    // Button Settings
    button_image_url : "XPButtonUploadText_61x22.png",
    button_placeholder_id : "spanButtonPlaceholder",
    button_width: 61,
    button_height: 22,

    // Flash Settings
    flash_url : "../swfupload/swfupload.swf",

    custom_settings : {
     progress_target : "fsUploadProgress",
     upload_successful : false
    },

    // Debug settings
    debug: false
   });

  };
 </script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Call `swfu` method `cancelUpload` ([ref](http://demo.swfupload.org/Documentation/#cancelUpload)) from a button click or something.